# Missing Server Side Dependencies for Custom wsp packages in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin

I have a sharepoint farm that has 2 WFE+1 APP +1 SQL server architecture. I have deployed a solution package which contains webparts and a few things related to site level.

It warns me that the setup files, webparts are missing in the central administration even though the solution packages are deployed the web application. BTW, there is a web application on the farm.

I have checked the below articles. But in those articles offers the deploy the solutions for whole web applications on the farm. Furthermore, one of those articles is related to search webpart and the another of them is related to default webpart in the admin_ content db. But my issue is related to custom solution files that is in the wss_content db.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/christianheim/2016/09/15/missing-server-side-dependencies-errors-on-your-multi-server-sharepoint-farm/

https://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/sharepoint-2013missing-serverside-dependencies/